# How do I swap 2 parts of s string?

Tags: python, string, swap

I'm trynna swap 2 parts of a string like (1, 2, 3) and swap the 1 and 2 to get (2, 1, 3). I can provide extra clarification if needed.

Comment: Please provide extra clarification. What do the strings actually look like? Those seem to be tuples of ints. You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Yes, we need clarification. Is the string defined as `x = '(1, 2, 3)'`? Should the comma be treated as a separator? Do you need to swap two neighboring values or could they be anywhere in the string?

Comment: The solution could be something like `data = list(ast.literal_eval(x))` followed by `data[0], data[1] = data[1], data[0]` and `print(str(tuple(data)))` but you need to give more information.

Comment: @Matthias Minor thing: `print(str())` is redundant. You can just do `print(tuple(data))`

Comment: @wjandrea Right, they will look the same. Printing the data isn't exactly what was asked. The correct solution might be `x = str(tuple(data))` so that we get a string again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant "(1, 2, 3)" (i.e. a string rather than a tuple) you could use the following function:

```
def swap(string, pos_from, pos_to):
    new_string = ""
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if i==pos_from: new_string += string[pos_to]
        elif i==pos_to: new_string += string[pos_from]
        else: new_string += char
    return new_string
```

So, in your example, all you need to do is provide the string and the positions you want to swap (remembering that in python positions start at 0):

```
In [0]: swap(string='(1,2,3)', pos_from=1, pos_to=3)
Out[0]: (2,1,3)
```

Comment: You could also convert the string to a list (`list(string_var)`) and then simply use indexes.

Comment: @Matiiss indeed, that would also do the trick

Comment: Just for fun an evil one-liner solution for this approach. The whole function body will look like this:  `return ''.join(string[pos_from] if i == pos_to else string[pos_to] if i == pos_from else c for i, c in enumerate(string))`

Comment: @Matthias whilst I find your solution very intellectually exciting, I'm not sure EsoTorrent will understand it (given that he is new to StackOverflow and all... ;) )

Comment: @Mike You're right of course. That's why I said "just for fun" and "evil". In real code I would use a better readable approach. Unfortunately EsoTorrent wasn't active in the 30 minutes since the question was asked despite offering extra clarification.